# Flask-Admin override default view with a ModelView class?

Tags: flask-admin

As described [here](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_base/) you can override the the default view of Flask-Admin by declaring a child class of AdminIndexView and passing the view to the admin app. Is it possible to override the the default view with a ModelView class view? If so how would I go about doing that? I only really need ModelViews for my admin panel and can't figure out how to get rid of the default view. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it if you give the endpoint 'admin' to your model view, as in:

```
admin = Admin(app, url='/', index_view=MyModelView(my_model, db.session, url='/', endpoint='admin'))
```